# Move Sharepoint Site and Maintain Word Document Hyperlinks

Tags: export, word

My client currently has a Sharepoint site that they need to move to a completely different server.   This site has quite a few pages, and also several Word documents that have embedded hyperlinks to other areas of the Sharepoint site, as well as other Word documents.   When trying to move this site in the past, those Hyperlinks would break, as the relative locations of the files had changed.

What's the best way that the Sharepoint site can be configured to allow for portability that will maintain the embedded linking, even under a different URL?   Also, what would be the best way to move this site to an entirely different Sharepoint server?

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your farm virtual or physical? If it's virtual it shouldn't be a problem moving the farm to another server keeping the URL's as is.

Comment: The originating server is physical, though I'm not sure what the resulting location is, as it's owned by an entirely different organization.  I'd assume it's a physical location as well.  As for the URLs, they wouldn't be the same between the two servers.

My client is a local municipality, and every few years, they need to have their documentation and information filed with another group. When this occurs, everything needs to be packaged as-is, and moved to this other group's server.  None of the contents can link back to the original document, and everything needs to be self-contained.

Comment: You could just backup and restore this site elsewhere and see if there are any broken links.